# Why does `xdg-mime query filetype ...` fail to find a new added file type?

Tags: linux, mime-types, freedesktop

I installed a new file type to share MIME database. But `xdg-mime query filetype` cannot tell the new type. This problem only happens on my own Linux OS which does not use GNOME or KDE as its desktop. On Ubuntu, the same process works well.

I found that `xdg-mime query filetype` uses "file -i filename" under the hood on my OS but uses gnomevfs on Ubuntu.

Here are my steps:

1. wrote a xml file for my new file type `my_file.xml`
2. `xdg-mime install my_file.xml`
3. `xdg-mime query filetype` <name of file to query>  .... no output :-(

I checked `/usr/share/mime/applications` and found the xml entry generated by update-mime-database there. And the C API `g_file_info_get_content_type()` can get the proper mime type.

So it seems the shared-mime-info has been updated successfully. But the "file" command still fails, why?

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/vnd.xxx.xxx.xxx">
        <comment>xxxx</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.dcf"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Comment: My destop system is neither GNOME or KDE. The debug info "Running file -i..." and I found it run to info_generic():
{
    DEBUG 1 "Running file -i \"$1\""
    /usr/bin/file -i "$1" 2> /dev/null | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed s/"^ "//

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        exit_success
    else
        exit_failure_operation_failed
    fi
}

Comment: If you dont have any desktop enviroment, you should not use `xdg-mime` (or any other xdg tool). xdg is meant to provide interoperability between different desktop enviroments, but *not* when there is none. Think of xdg as *desktop-agnostic, but **not** "desktop-atheist"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I find the answer. On my system `xdg-mime query filetype ...` uses the `file` command to get the file type, while on Ubuntu it uses `gnomevfs`.

It seems the `file` command does not check XML entries of shared-mime-info, but looks into the file `/usr/share/file/magic` to get the file MIME type.

If I use `file` command on Ubuntu, it can not tell me the right MIME type, either.

I'll study how to edit this magic file.

Comment: There are two different MIME databases. `file` uses the unix traditional `/etc/magic` (and other `…/magic`). [`xdg-mime`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html) uses the [Freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/) database (when it's available).

Comment: @Giles: xdg-mime uses Freedesktop database when it is avaliable *and and there is a DE (like Gnome or KDE) installed to actually read the database*. Since OP has no DE, xdg-mime has no tools to query its own database, and falls back to `file`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-MimeInfo/ (or your distro's package for this) which contains the `mimetype` utility.

After installing this package, `xdg-mime` (tested version 1.1.0 rc1 on Arch Linux) should now detect that `mimetype` (which *does* use the XDG shared mime info database) is available, and use that instead of falling back on `file -i`.

Comment: The command seems to be `mimetype` in ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. `apt-get install libfile-mimeinfo-perl` if it's not there.

Comment: @GnP Same here, thanks for mentioning. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This solution won't work if `kde`, `gnome`, `cinnamon`, `lxde`, `mate` or `xfce` is installed as a Desktop Environment.