# wrong mime-type displayed for empty text files

Tags: mime-types, nemo

I have tried to install a new mime-type for textfiles with a `.w` extension as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- In file ~/.local/share/mime/packages/w.xml -->
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/w">
    <comment>File of w type</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.w" />
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

After running `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`, any *non-empty* file with the extension `.w` is correctly identified in my file-browser as being a **text/w** file. However, *if* that file is empty, then it is identified simply as **text/plain** instead.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug or is it expected behaviour? Is there any way to also get *empty* files with a `.w` extension to show up as being of type **text/w**?

---

**Update:** using the `mimetype` command (as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283601/229444)), as opposed to `xdg-mime query filetype` or `file --mime-type` returns the right result even if the file is empty. So presumably the partial answer to my question is that presumably nemo relies on xdg-mime internally. Is there any way to fix this in general via the mime xml definition, or should I simply be raising a bug to nemo to use mimetype instead of xdg-mime instead?

Comment: There is now a formal bug request on github on this: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/1792

Comment: If you ever found a solution to this, it would be great if you post the answer. I'm having the same problem with my own mime type with empty files using xdg-mime...